Applying for a Canadian Transit Visa with Multiple Layovers One Month Apart
I have a round trip flight from USA to India. The ongoing flight is in November and the returning flight is in December. Both the flights have a layover in Canada for less an hour. I am applying for Canadian transit Visa. What should you enter in "WHEN WILL YOU ENTER" and "WHEN WILL YOU LEAVE" sections of my transit visa application? I am confused because website says the duration between "WHEN WILL YOU ENTER" and "WHEN WILL YOU LEAVE" should be 48 hours, however, I will be transiting through Canada twice -- one in November and one in December? Do I have to submit two applications?


Are you in the correct page? From the title in bold (of your image), it seems a temporary resident (but maybe they do not distinguish the transit case). In any case, I would put only the first transit (and maybe a note about you need the visa for the return travel). But Less then 1 hour is a bit optimistic for intercontinental travels. Arrival times, and times when you are inside airport is different, and then further checks... Reconsider your timings

Is this a self-transfer or on a single ticket (one PNR)?

Enter the dates of your outbound and return transits. A transit visa can be valid for 1 or 2 entries, depending on your travel plans. Make sure to choose ‘two’ as the number of entries you’re applying for.
Note that a transit visa is only valid for airside transit. A connection time of less than one hour is tight when you take into account the time needed to de-plane and get to the departure gate before it closes.
Edit: in case it helps, searching for an example of a Canadian transit visa, I found this one, which has a 6 month validity period, limited to two entries.

Why should it be "return transit"? My guess it it should be foward transit, because the visa will be provide from the forward transit date onwards

@user3619023 It’s only a turn of phrase. It could just as easily say ‘second transit’ or ‘subsequent transit’. The OP states ‘round trip flight’ in their question, so ‘return transit’ seemed the obvious choice of phrase.

@user3619023 I’ve edited my answer to clarify.
